# Multiple Voice_Call for a TimelineItem

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Is it possible to have multiple VOICE_CALL options for a given TimelineItem? A scenario would be that I have a Store that has multiple contact numbers. One would be for the 800 number while a second option would be to call a specific store location directly. I have tried adding multiple MenuItems whose action is VOICE_CALL, but not surprisingly it only recognizes the first. Is something like this possible with custom menu items? I am currently writing this in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet possible with the API. Please file a feature request on our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) if you'd like to see this implemented.